# process image and group into similar type using weka

Tags: image-processing, weka, data-mining

I am new to image processing and data mining. I have a task of processing the images to find the different type of faults in it like processing images of metal sheets produced by steel plants which are gray in color and finding faults by may be color change or length etc. For this i have to group them in different classes first. I have searched but haven't got anything. Any kind of help would be great.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm thinking a few sample images would help... originals and some marked up with the defects as well.

Comment: Right now i have one image. You can see that the color is not same and there is line in middle which is a defect type. normal image will be of same color throughout

Comment: so you don't have a training set?

Comment: I have but the file is big. i have added screen shot in question.